# How can Nginx be configured to serve stale responses while attempting to update the response?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I have an API that takes a long time to generate a response. I want to use Nginx's fastcgi_cache to prevent users from waiting for the response. I have enabled the cache and it's functioning well. However, the issue arises when the cache expires.

I want to update the response in the background and serve all requests with the stale response. Currently, only the first request is served with the stale response, and subsequent requests remain pending until the new response is obtained from the server.

My current nginx configuration:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /usr/share/nginx/fastcgi_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=phpcache:10m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme://$request_method$host$request_uri-$http_accept_language";
fastcgi_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;

server {
    ...

    location ~ ^/index.php(/|$) {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_cache phpcache;
        fastcgi_cache_background_update on;
        fastcgi_cache_lock on;
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating;
        add_header X-FastCGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        ...
    }
```

The response's headers:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, public, stale-while-revalidate=50
Vary: Accept-Language
```